# Replace object with mock at the reference location in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP project I have main singleton and some other singletons that uses the main one:

```
<?php

class SingletonMain
{
    // Main singleton
    // ...
}

class SingletonA
{
    protected $main;

    function __construct()
    {
        $main = SingletonMain::getInstance();
    }
}

class SingletonB
{
    protected $main;

    function __construct()
    {
        $main = SingletonMain::getInstance();
    }
}
?>
```

I thought, maybe the easiest way to mock **SingletonMain** in **SingletonA** and **SingletonB** is by getting a reference to **SingletonMain** instance and performing this:

1. Copy **SingletonMain** instance to `$temp`.
2. Put **MockSingletonMain** instance in place of **SingletonMain**. By 'in place' I mean really, in the same reference location so that **SingletonA** and **SingletonB** could use a new mock immediately as if it was the original **SingletonMain**.
3. Test.
4. Revert **SingletonMain** instance from `$temp` in place.

Is that possible to do? If not, what is the easiest way to mock **SingletonMain** in all **SingletonsABCD**....

Currently, my only solution in mind is to explicitly set new mock in each of these leaf singletons and revert it once again in the end using normal assignment operator (`$this->main = $my_mock` and after testing `$this->main = SingletonMain::getInstance()`).

**EDIT**

By reading several answers, I realized, I need to provide some more info. I have around 20-30 of these leaf singletons. The application was not designed to be tested in the first place several years ago, so now I am looking for the best way to go around the singleton pattern without breaking anything and changing as little as possible.

Comment: FYI, the simplest way to test singletons is to **not use singletons**. They're generally considered an anti-pattern and `static` is famously hard to test. You should be injecting dependencies into your objects, not accessing global state through static instances.

Answer (score 0):

SingletonA is not a singleton in your code, so you can easily pass the mocked SingletonMain instance in the test:

```
class SingletonA
{
    protected $main;

    function __construct($main = null)
    {
        if (!$main) $main = SingletonMain::getInstance();
        $this->main = $main;
    }
}
```

If none is passed fall back to the current behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is inheritance. Like this:

```
class SingletonA extends SingletonMain {
    // Your code specific to SingletonA here.
}

class SingletonB extends SingletonMain {
    // Your code specific to SingletonB here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating test-stubs:

```
class SingletonAStub extends SingletonA
{

    public function getMain() {
        return $this->main;
    }

    public function setMain($main) {
        $this->main = $main;
    }
}
```

In your tests you use the stub, change the "singleton" as you need to and test.

Naturally it's much better to just not make use of singletons firsthand, so you don't have so much need to create special sub-types only for testing.